# Analytic map from $\{|z|<1 \}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \Re(w) \geq 1/4 , \Im(w)=0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find an injective analytic map from $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1 \}$ to $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ \Re(w) \geq 1/4 , \Im(w)=0  \}$ so that $f(0)=0$ and
>   $|f'(0)|>0.$

My attempt:

I used

$$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z-1}(1-i)$$

to map the unit circle to the left half plane. I tought about using $g(z)=z^2$ in order to "get rid" of the negative real axis but then I get the entire plane but the negative real axis. Plus, I have no idea how to guarantee that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$.

Comment: Are there other conditions, or is it just "injective"? Doesn't the map $f(z) = \frac14 z$ work in this case?

Comment: @nik: Well, it is not injective and the deriative is zero.

Comment: Err... It is injective (if $\frac14 z = \frac14 z'$ then $z=z'$), and $f'(0) = \frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Möbius-Transformation from $\{|z|<1\}$ to $\mathbb{H}$ the upper half space. use $z\mapsto z^2$ (notice that this map is biholomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$)and then just add $1/4$. Then you have what you want, because the composition of bijective holomorphic maps is biholomorphic.

You use the Möbius transformation for the left half plane, mutiply it with $-i$ and you get the upper half-plane. this is explicive $z\mapsto i \frac{1+z}{1-z}$.

The additional condition can be easy computed. use $0 \mapsto i \mapsto -1 \mapsto -\frac{3}{4}$. So you just have to use $z\mapsto \frac{1}{4} z^2$ as the map in the middle.

That the differential is not $0$ can be computed in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Mebat, but I dont see it - wouldn't $z\mapsto z^2$ give us the entire plane excluding the positive real numbers?

Comment: No because theere is $\mathbb{H}$ has no boundary (it's open). So you just send the first quadrant to the upper half plane and the second quadrant to the lower half plane, the positive imaginary axis gives us the negative real axis after squaring. so we obtain $\mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. That doesn't help us since we need only half of the plane...

Comment: Because of that, we are translating it, after $z\mapsto z^2 \frac{1}{4}$.